# Errors getting apache working with fcgi and suexec

Tags: apache-2.2, php, suexec

I have a Debian 6 server and I was previously using Apache with mod_php but decided to switch to using fcgi instead since Wordpress was somehow causing Apache to crash. I have the following in my site's Apache config file:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 .php

SuexecUserGroup "#1001" "#1003"
```

Everything works fine if I don't include the `SuexecUserGroup`, but it obviously then runs the script as `www-data` instead of the user and group above. When I include that line, I get a 500 error and the following shows up in my `suexec.log` file:

```
[2013-05-22 16:00:12]: command not in docroot (/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5)
```

Everything was installed using the packages, so I don't even know where the docroot *is*.

Here is my suexec info:

```
# /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V
 -D SUEXEC_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/apache2/suexec/
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/apache2/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=100
```

And the permissions on my php5 file if that has anything to do with it:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7769160 Mar  4 08:25 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
```

Answer (score 0):

The document root in the error message is the `suexec` document root. For security reasons, you cannot directly use any `FCGIWrapper` commands that are not contained within your suexec directory. By default, this is `/var/www/`, however when using `apache2-suexec-custom`, you can change this to whatever directory you want by modifying the first line in the `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data` file.